# ng-repeat in ionic doesn't show complete data although complete data is being fetched from the service and also showing up in console

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

In Ionic framework while using ng-repeat(angular) to show data in list format , I am not able to view all data, even though complete data is fetched from the service and I can also see all the data in console.

As per my understanding due to headers and two menus at the top the data is being truncated.

Please help me to resolve the issues.

Here is code which I have used,

```
 <ion-content class="has-footer">
        <ion-list>
            <ion-item ng-repeat="data in vm.bulkData">
                <div ng-repeat="(key,value) in data">
              <div ng-click="show=show==true? false:true;"class="item item-list">
                        <table class="weather-forecast-list">
                            <tr>
                                <td class="date">
                                     <p><b>{{value.date}}</b></p>
                                     <p>{{value.day}}</p>
                                </td>
                                <td class="date">
                                     <p>{{value.description}}</p>
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <img ng-src="{{value.icon}}" class="weather-icon-background"/>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>

                  <div ng-show="show" class="more_details">
                            <table class="weather-forecast-details">
                                <tr>
                                    <td><p>Temperature</p></td>
                                    <td><p>{{value.temp_day}}&degC</p></td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td><p>Wind</p></td>
                                    <td><p>{{value.wind}}m/s</p></td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td><p>Pressure</p></td>
                                    <td><p>{{value.pressure}}mb</p></td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td><p>Humidity</p></td>
                                    <td><p>{{value.humidity}}%</p></td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>
                  </div>
                    </div>
            </div>
            </ion-item>
        </ion-list>
    </ion-content>
```

**Controller**

```
   /******************controller******/
    vm.weatherData = weatherAnalyticsLocationDataSvc;
    var onBulkDataReturned = function(bulkData){
        vm.bulkData = bulkData;
    };
    var onError = function(reason){
        vm.error = reason;
    };
    manipulateWeatherDataSvc.getManipulatedWeatherData(weatherAnalyticsLocationDataSvc).then(onBulkDataReturned, onError);
```

where weatherAnalyticsLocationDataSvc is a service.

Comment: Can you provide some code.

Comment: Updated the question  with code

Comment: please show your controller code where you get value from service in vm.bulkData

Comment: problem is not the data, there is the issue with the ionic css components. I am getting complete data in view.